# Admob banner ads and screen sizes

Tags: android, admob

My problem, i have an app which i want to show admob banner ads, but only in layout/screen sizes for tablets 7" and 10". And just because there is more room for banner ads, because bigger screen size. Now the problem is that when banner ads works perfect in 7" and 10" tablets, but with normal and small screen size devices i get error/crash, because there is no adview in its xml layout. So my question is, how to prevent the admob banner view on certain layouts correctly. Or whether it is even possible?